# How do you eject the samsung device when the device is currently being used for testing using the Android-ADT

Tags: usb, usb-connection-mode, usb-debugging

[image]I connected my Samsung Device(Android 4.1.2 ) for testing my app through the Android-ADT(Eclipse).

- After closing the workspace when I tried to eject the device through
  Eject I get a dialog box saying the phone is currently being used
  please close any running software using the phone.

  Thereby forcing me to unplug the device manually.
- Any help appreciated.

Comment: From command prompt try `adb kill-server`  and then eject

Comment: @Sameer it wonderfully worked by terminating the server from command prompt

Comment: Okay I will make that as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From command prompt you can enter the following command

```
adb kill-server
```

and then try ejecting.

Answer (score 1):

The dialog you mention is nothing to do with USB debugging: it's because the device's storage is mounted (via MTP or USB mass storage), and some app has a file open from that storage. It could be that you have a file manager window looking at the device's storage, or that your music player software is automatically indexing files on it, or something else.

To avoid the dialog, you need to find and close whatever software *on your desktop computer* has files from the phone open. On Linux you can use the `lsof` tool to help; on Windows you just have to guess.